# Is it possible to recover my HDD?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, recovery-partition

I re-installed my Windows 10 and found that my Seagate 2TB HDD is missing.

After I installed an appropriate driver, my OS detected the HDD, but it was a dynamic disk.

To change the dynamic to basic, I followed some instructions without backup and accidentally erased the volume of HDD.

**What I did: Removed a volume from the HDD and converted it to a basic drive with 'diskpart' on Windows poweshell.**

My question is:
Is it possible to recover my HDD? Its current status is 'unformatted,' and I did not touch the disk anymore right after I removed a volume (no format)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"I followed some instructions"_ - please describe exactly what you did. You can [edit] the question to include this information.

Answer (score 2):

Try [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and/or [PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec). If TestDisk can't recover the hard disk, try PhotoRec. Be warned it likes to spit out a very large amount of data, and be prepared to give it a large space to write the recovered data to. Both take quite a while (Maybe an entire day or two for something as large as 2TB)

Can you give a link to the tutorial you followed? It might help describe what happened to your drive. I would expect the partition table got incinerated.

Comment: +1 for testdisk.   Its probably a good idea to also advise doing a bitcopy backup before attempting this (or any) recovery.

Comment: I cannot find whrlere the tutorial was, but I just erased a volume with diskpart on Windows poweshell. I tried testdisk, and it found the NTFS partition I removed. However, I got the error message 'cannot recover partition. Disk space is too small' something like that. If I prepare another empty 4TB disk, is it possible to restore my 2TB disk?

Comment: 4TB should be good. How big was the one you tried with TestDisk but got `Disk space is too small`?

Comment: Error said that it requires 2.5TB. But I am just curious if I can use an external HDD instead of in-place recovery.

Comment: That's odd. I accidentally targeted a boot drive while writing a disk image using dd (Linux tool for copying data, but often used for cloning and writing to disks), and it incinerated the partition table, along with a lot of data. But after TestDisk (on a different machine) found the remaining partitions it let me write a new partition table rendering the usable partitions read/writable again, without the need for a recovery drive. I'll edit my question if you need me to show how to do such.